# Multiple form search in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I created a website with ads and I would like to have a search form with multiple dropdown fields (i.e. price, type, etc.). The main title search form would be optional. How can I aachieve this using Views? Or maybe it is better to use some module? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with Views, which is probably the easiest way, you need to use exposed_filters. Lullabot have made an excellent [guide for Drupal 5](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/custom-search-forms-views-and-fastsearch), a few things are have changed in Drupal 6, like you don't need fast search anymore and the UI is a bit different, but the principals are the same.